# How to conditionally assign a struct to a variable?

Tags: swift, dictionary, variables, struct

The code is pretty self explanatory. I am trying to have the dictionary variable be one of 3 structs. There is likely a simple solution that escapes me at the moment.

```
func whichDictionaryToUse(flaps: Int, wind: Int) {

var dictionary = ()
var possibleWindDictionaries = Set<[Double:Double]>()

switch flaps {
case 10: dictionary = CorrectLD10Dict()
case 15: dictionary = CorrectLD15Dict()
case 35: dictionary = CorrectLD35Dict()
default: print("Present alert saying flaps value out of range")
}

switch wind {
  case 10: possibleWindDictionaries = [dictionary.plusTenMinusTwoDic, dictionary.plusTenMinusOneDic, dictionary.plusTenZeroDic, dictionary.plusTenPlusOneDic, dictionary.plusTenPlusTwoDic]
 …
```

Comment: Create a protocol which all three `Correct....` types conform to and declare `dictionary` as this protocol type

Comment: In your code, `dictionary` is of type `Void`, which is pointless to assign to...

Comment: Not to mention the name is quite confusing, having a `dictionary` variable be of a non-dictionary type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Implementation using structs is below:**

```
struct CorrectLD10Dict: CorrectLDict {
    var plusTenMinusTwoDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenMinusOneDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenZeroDic     = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusOneDic  = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusTwoDic  = [Double : Double]()
}
struct CorrectLD15Dict: CorrectLDict {
    var plusTenMinusTwoDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenMinusOneDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenZeroDic     = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusOneDic  = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusTwoDic  = [Double : Double]()
}
struct CorrectLD35Dict: CorrectLDict {
    var plusTenMinusTwoDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenMinusOneDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenZeroDic     = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusOneDic  = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusTwoDic  = [Double : Double]()
}

protocol CorrectLDict {
    var plusTenMinusTwoDic: [Double:Double] { get set }
    var plusTenMinusOneDic: [Double:Double] { get set }
    var plusTenZeroDic    : [Double:Double] { get set }
    var plusTenPlusOneDic : [Double:Double] { get set }
    var plusTenPlusTwoDic : [Double:Double] { get set }

}



func whichDictionaryToUse(flaps: Int, wind: Int) {

    var dictionary: CorrectLDict? = nil
    var possibleWindDictionaries = Set<[Double:Double]>()

    switch flaps {
    case 10: dictionary = CorrectLD10Dict()
    case 15: dictionary = CorrectLD15Dict()
    case 35: dictionary = CorrectLD35Dict()
    default: print("Present alert saying flaps value out of range")
    }

    guard let dictionary = dictionary else { return }

    switch wind {
    case 10: possibleWindDictionaries = [dictionary.plusTenMinusTwoDic, dictionary.plusTenMinusOneDic, dictionary.plusTenZeroDic, dictionary.plusTenPlusOneDic, dictionary.plusTenPlusTwoDic]
    default:
        print("")
    }

}
```

**Implementation using classes is below:**

```
   class CorrectLDict {
    var plusTenMinusTwoDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenMinusOneDic = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenZeroDic     = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusOneDic  = [Double : Double]()
    var plusTenPlusTwoDic  = [Double : Double]()
}

class CorrectLD10Dict: CorrectLDict  {}
class CorrectLD15Dict: CorrectLDict {}
class CorrectLD35Dict: CorrectLDict {}

func whichDictionaryToUse(flaps: Int, wind: Int) {
    
    var dictionary: CorrectLDict? = nil
    var possibleWindDictionaries = Set<[Double:Double]>()
    
    switch flaps {
    case 10: dictionary = CorrectLD10Dict()
    case 15: dictionary = CorrectLD15Dict()
    case 35: dictionary = CorrectLD35Dict()
    default: print("Present alert saying flaps value out of range")
    }
    
    guard let dictionary = dictionary else { return }
    
    switch wind {
    case 10: possibleWindDictionaries = [dictionary.plusTenMinusTwoDic, dictionary.plusTenMinusOneDic, dictionary.plusTenZeroDic, dictionary.plusTenPlusOneDic, dictionary.plusTenPlusTwoDic]
    default:
        print("")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This look very promising, however I’m getting an error in the switch wind statement as dictionary remains of type CorrectLDDict, it seems that the switch flaps statement doesn’t take effect

Comment: @AvsBest I updated my previous answer, so you can see full implementation. +also variant using classes and inheritance intead of structs.